# Create global variables

Tags: vba, excel

Bit of a newbie to VBA, sorry

I need to create some variables that are available throughout my workbook, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've read in previous questions where some people have suggested create a separate dim for this?

When the workbook opens I need to set some variables equal to certain cells in a worksheet, these variables need to be called from dims in others worksheets.

So far I have tried to use

Workbook_Open()

In the 'ThisWorkbook' code area but to no avail.

Any tips?

Reagards

EDIT ----

I have tried with the following:

In 'ThisWorkbook'

```
Public wsDrawings As String
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
     wsDrawings = "Hello"
End Sub
```

And in Sheet1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox wsDrawings
End Sub
```

I do not get an error, but the message box is empty.

Comment: are you going to have a few Modules inside with VBA ? or just use these variables for all Worksheets ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variable with code like this

`Public testVar As String`

you need to place it outside `function` or `sub` and then this variable has value till you close workbook. But i think it have scope only in current module.

So you can have something like this

```
Public testVar As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

testVar = "test"
End Sub

Sub testEcho()

MsgBox testVar
End Sub
```

for shared variable between multiple modules look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889202/is-there-a-way-to-use-local-variables-across-modules)

edit:

So now i found, that you can use public variable from ThisWorkbook using this

```
Sub testSub()

    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.wsDrawings
End Sub
```

Comment: I couln't get this to work for me, I've copied the code I used above, any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisBull look at end of my answer now, i think i got something

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the variables you need wherever they are first used (ThisWorkbook is a fine place to do it) and replace the typical `Dim` with `Public`.  It will then be accessable in all your code

Answer (score -1):

you can use module for creating global variable.